# SoundCloud Widget API play(), pause(), toggle() methods don't toggle the play/pause button image in the player

Tags: soundcloud

Check it out on the [SoundCloud Widget API Playground](http://w.soundcloud.com/player/api_playground.html) for example. If you click the play, pause, and toggle buttons, the big orange play/pause button in the widget doesn't update.

I've checked in up-to-date versions of Chrome, Safari, and Firefox on Mac OS X 10.7.5.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this, we are investigating.

Comment: You're welcome. Also happens if you click on a specific track in a playlist/set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix has just been deployed.